# parseInt on string "802.11 auth" doesn't return what I expected

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm writing a parser that converts the output of a command into a JSON object that I can push to a realtime logging and graphing service. Everything comes out of the parser as strings, and I'd like numbers to come out as numbers, but I'm having a small problem.

I know that parseInt(string) returns NaN if you use a non-parseable string. The problem I have is that the string '802.11 auth' can be parsed by parseInt to 802, which is definitely not what I want.

wat do. I'm currently hacking it by checking the last character in the string, but it's an inelegant solution.

```
blackjack:~ sent1nel$ cat whatever.js
console.log(parseInt("802.11 auth"));
blackjack:~ sent1nel$ node whatever.js
802
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use a Regex to validate the contents before you try converting to numbers. It's not clear from your question what validation you're actually trying to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unary plus operator to convert a string rather than parsing it:

```
+"802.11" // 802.11
+"802.11 auth" // NaN
```

Comment: This is cute, works, and didn't involve a regex match. Fabulous.

Comment: Oh, to actually see it in use... https://gist.github.com/sent1nel/cd4eba3b1118e6510aeb/revisions

Revision is 2452078d8c6d6698ff43f16c47faa8537102ec0a

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know if a variable is a number:

```
var s = "802.11 auth";
s == +s
> false // the string s is not convertible into a number

var s2 = "802.11";
s2 == +s2
> true // the string s2 is convertible into a number
```

If you want to extract the number:

```
var s = "802.11 auth";
var number1 = + s.match(/[\d.]/g).join(''); // 802.11
var number2 = Number(s.match(/[\d.]/g).join('')); // 802.11
```

If you only want `802` you can use `parseInt()`:

```
 var number3 = parseInt(s.match(/[\d.]/g).join('')); // 802
```

Comment: Good answer, though I don't actually care about the 802. I really just want to know if a string is a number or not, so I don't throw strings into number fields in my db, because that would totally mess up my graphs.

Comment: If you only want to know if it is a number you can do (assuming that the var n is a number): `n === +n`. If true n is a number, otherwise is some other kind of variable.